# Is it possible to mark a test as pending in MiniTest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, minitest

And if this is possible, what is the syntax for this?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

It took me a few minutes poking around on the RubyDocs to figure out the actual syntax for pulling this off. Figured I'd toss it here to save some future person a few clicks.

From inside your test, simply call the `skip()` method, like so:

```
skip("reason for skipping the test")
```

The method is `MiniTest::Assertions#skip` - http://docs.seattlerb.org/minitest/Minitest/Assertions.html#method-i-skip

Comment: Here is a current link to the documentation: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/minitest/rdoc/MiniTest/Assertions.html#method-i-skip

Answer (score 11):

I figured this out. With minitest you don't mark tests as pending. But you can skip them:

http://docs.seattlerb.org/minitest/Minitest/Assertions.html#method-i-skip

Comment: this link is not working anymore, can you add answer instead of link.

Comment: phinze has the correct syntax in his answer. I changed the accepted answer to his.

Answer (score 8):

Also, when using MiniTest::Spec, if you don't pass a block to it(), the test is marked as skipped.